# Error installing QtLocation

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.4

So I'm trying to install QtLocation.
I created the qt5vars.cmd in C:\QT exactly with the text stated.
This is my error:

```
C:\QT\QT5>REM Set up \Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, where <arch> is \c
amd64, \c x86, etc.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\QT\QT5>CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\
vcvarsall.bat" <arch>

C:\QT\QT5>configure -debug -nomake examples -opensource
'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\QT\QT5>
```

Can anyone point me to the problem? I just installed Microsoft Visual studio and it is located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
```

Edit: Found out that the problem was that I needed to add x86, besides only the complete backage consists of the make and configure so therefor I downloaded the complete package.

Now I have a new error

```
    moc_qqmlenginedebugservice_p.cpp
moc_qdebugmessageservice_p.cpp
moc_qv4debugservice_p.cpp
moc_qqmlconfigurabledebugservice_p.cpp
moc_qqmlabstractprofileradapter_p.cpp
moc_qv4profileradapter_p.cpp
moc_qqmlprofiler_p.cpp
moc_qabstractanimationjob_p.cpp
moc_qqmlbind_p.cpp
moc_qqmlconnections_p.cpp
moc_qqmldelegatemodel_p.cpp
moc_qqmldelegatemodel_p_p.cpp
moc_qqmllistmodel_p.cpp
moc_qqmllistmodel_p_p.cpp
moc_qqmllistmodelworkeragent_p.cpp
moc_qqmlobjectmodel_p.cpp
moc_qqmltimer_p.cpp
moc_qquickpackage_p.cpp
moc_qquickworkerscript_p.cpp
Generating Code...
        link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /BASE:0x66000000 /DEBUG /DLL /SUBSYS
TEM:WINDOWS /VERSION:5.40 /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:C:\TUecomotive\QT5\qt-everywhere-
opensource-src-5.4.0\qtbase\lib\Qt5Qmld.dll @C:\Users\s130031\AppData\Local\Temp
\nm9C7.tmp
   Creating library C:\TUecomotive\QT5\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0\qtbase
\lib\Qt5Qmld.lib and object C:\TUecomotive\QT5\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.
0\qtbase\lib\Qt5Qmld.exp
YarrInterpreter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yar
r::CharacterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::newlineCreate(void)" (?newlineCreate@Yarr
@JSC@@YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct JSC::Yar
r::CharacterClass * __thiscall JSC::Yarr::YarrPattern::newlineCharacterClass(voi
d)" (?newlineCharacterClass@YarrPattern@Yarr@JSC@@QAEPAUCharacterClass@23@XZ)
YarrPattern.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yarr::C
haracterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::newlineCreate(void)" (?newlineCreate@Yarr@JSC
@@YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ)
YarrInterpreter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yar
r::CharacterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::wordcharCreate(void)" (?wordcharCreate@Ya
rr@JSC@@YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct JSC::Y
arr::CharacterClass * __thiscall JSC::Yarr::YarrPattern::wordcharCharacterClass(
void)" (?wordcharCharacterClass@YarrPattern@Yarr@JSC@@QAEPAUCharacterClass@23@XZ
)
YarrPattern.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yarr::C
haracterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::wordcharCreate(void)" (?wordcharCreate@Yarr@J
SC@@YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ)
YarrPattern.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yarr::C
haracterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::digitsCreate(void)" (?digitsCreate@Yarr@JSC@@
YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct JSC::Yarr::Cha
racterClass * __thiscall JSC::Yarr::YarrPattern::digitsCharacterClass(void)" (?d
igitsCharacterClass@YarrPattern@Yarr@JSC@@QAEPAUCharacterClass@23@XZ)
YarrPattern.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yarr::C
haracterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::spacesCreate(void)" (?spacesCreate@Yarr@JSC@@
YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct JSC::Yarr::Cha
racterClass * __thiscall JSC::Yarr::YarrPattern::spacesCharacterClass(void)" (?s
pacesCharacterClass@YarrPattern@Yarr@JSC@@QAEPAUCharacterClass@23@XZ)
YarrPattern.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yarr::C
haracterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::nondigitsCreate(void)" (?nondigitsCreate@Yarr
@JSC@@YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct JSC::Yar
r::CharacterClass * __thiscall JSC::Yarr::YarrPattern::nondigitsCharacterClass(v
oid)" (?nondigitsCharacterClass@YarrPattern@Yarr@JSC@@QAEPAUCharacterClass@23@XZ
)
YarrPattern.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yarr::C
haracterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::nonspacesCreate(void)" (?nonspacesCreate@Yarr
@JSC@@YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct JSC::Yar
r::CharacterClass * __thiscall JSC::Yarr::YarrPattern::nonspacesCharacterClass(v
oid)" (?nonspacesCharacterClass@YarrPattern@Yarr@JSC@@QAEPAUCharacterClass@23@XZ
)
YarrPattern.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct JSC::Yarr::C
haracterClass * __cdecl JSC::Yarr::nonwordcharCreate(void)" (?nonwordcharCreate@
Yarr@JSC@@YAPAUCharacterClass@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct JSC:
:Yarr::CharacterClass * __thiscall JSC::Yarr::YarrPattern::nonwordcharCharacterC
lass(void)" (?nonwordcharCharacterClass@YarrPattern@Yarr@JSC@@QAEPAUCharacterCla
ss@23@XZ)
C:\TUecomotive\QT5\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0\qtbase\lib\Qt5Qmld.dll : f
atal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\QT\QT5\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what are you trying to do? You are writing about QtLocation, but you are in some QT5 directory!

Comment: So I figured out 2 things.. 1, I did indeed forget to change <arch> and 2, only the QtLocation zip does not contain configure. So in order to use this I need to download the complete map..

Comment: I indeed needed to go one directory deeper however that did not change the error.

Comment: You cannot use configure in submodules. Also, what is a "complete map"?

Comment: So how to do it without configure then? With the complete map I refer to the 400/500 mb file that contains all the submodules

Comment: Simply just qmake. You do not need to build everything from scratch...

Comment: I am confused why you keep building Qt rather than just the desired module.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I found the answer here [Build Qt 5.4 in windows: use VS2010](http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.com/2015/03/build-qt-54-in-windows.html)  and here [Unresolved external symbol attempting to build 5.2](https://forum.qt.io/topic/32634/resolved-unresolved-external-symbol-attempting-to-build-5-2).

To solve this problem:

1. Check the file *QT_HOME\qtdeclarative\src\qml\RegExpJitTables.h* is empty or not. If it is empty, delete it. (In later versions the file is situated in each of the subdirectories of *QT_HOME\qtdeclarative\src\qml\.generated\* directory.)
2. make sure that python is in your PATH
3. nmake

It works for me.